# Cannot download data from DynamoDB

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk

Is anything wrong with my setting?It just return a empty array to me. No error message. "arn:aws:dynamodb:us-east-1:018671674304:table/auflyer-mobilehub-1884545339-Cusonmers/index/*" I add this code after I read it from somewhere else. But got no luck.

[image]

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "dynamodb:BatchGetItem",
                "dynamodb:BatchWriteItem",
                "dynamodb:DeleteItem",
                "dynamodb:GetItem",
                "dynamodb:PutItem",
                "dynamodb:Query",
                "dynamodb:UpdateItem"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:dynamodb:us-east-1:018671674304:table/auflyer-mobilehub-1884545339-Cusonmers",
                "arn:aws:dynamodb:us-east-1:018671674304:table/auflyer-mobilehub-1884545339-Cusonmers/index/searchByLastName",
                "arn:aws:dynamodb:us-east-1:018671674304:table/auflyer-mobilehub-1884545339-Cusonmers/index/searchByFirstName",
                "arn:aws:dynamodb:us-east-1:018671674304:table/auflyer-mobilehub-1884545339-Cusonmers/index/userId-fullName",
                "arn:aws:dynamodb:us-east-1:018671674304:table/auflyer-mobilehub-1884545339-Cusonmers/index/*"
            ],
            "Condition": {
                "ForAllValues:StringEquals": {
                    "dynamodb:LeadingKeys": [
                        "${cognito-identity.amazonaws.com:sub}",
                        "${accounts.google.com:sub}"
                    ]
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "dynamodb:BatchGetItem",
                "dynamodb:BatchWriteItem",
                "dynamodb:DeleteItem",
                "dynamodb:GetItem",
                "dynamodb:PutItem",
                "dynamodb:Query",
                "dynamodb:UpdateItem"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:dynamodb:us-east-1:018671674304:table/auflyer-mobilehub-1884545339-Cusonmers",
                "arn:aws:dynamodb:us-east-1:018671674304:table/auflyer-mobilehub-1884545339-Cusonmers/index/searchByLastName",
                "arn:aws:dynamodb:us-east-1:018671674304:table/auflyer-mobilehub-1884545339-Cusonmers/index/searchByFirstName",
                "arn:aws:dynamodb:us-east-1:018671674304:table/auflyer-mobilehub-1884545339-Cusonmers/index/userId-fullName",
                "arn:aws:dynamodb:us-east-1:018671674304:table/auflyer-mobilehub-1884545339-Cusonmers/index/*"
            ],
            "Condition": {
                "ForAllValues:StringEquals": {
                    "dynamodb:LeadingKeys": [
                        "${cognito-identity.amazonaws.com:sub}",
                        "${accounts.google.com:sub}"
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

[image]

Comment: If there are no errors & an empty array is returned then it doesn't look like a permissions issue. Try logging AWSIdentityManager.default().identityId before dynamodb call and make a similar Dynamodb call using AWS CLI. Do you see a value?